# How to write this query with Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I write this query with Zend Framework?

```
select
    log.log_date,
    log.user_id,
    log.task,
    log.work_desc,
    log.hours,
    log.user2project,
    project.title as title,
    project.id
from 
    log,
    project
where
    log.user2project = project.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much what you want.

```
$select = $this->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from('log', array('log_date', 'user_id', 'task', 'work_desc', 'hours', 'user2project'))
                ->join('project', 'log.user2project = project.id', array('title' => 'title', 'id'));
```

The code above just creates the `Zend_Db_Table_Select` object, it doesn't run the query. To run the query you will have to do the following:

```
$result = $this->fetchAll($select); //this results in a Zend_Db_Table_Rowset
//if you want to return an array, just do
return $result->toArray();
//if you want the rowset object just
return $result;
```

Comment: its returned me a huge array that is describing about whole schema.... But where are the values that this query should returned

Comment: @Awais Qarni : that's the object. If you want an array and not an object you have to call `toArray()` method on your result

Comment: @Awais Qarni: `toArray()` is a method you can call on a `Zend_Db_Table_Rowset` (aka a result object).